# What service/job is starting these reboots according to the output from `last`

Tags: boot, last

Have a few questions regarding the output below. One question is, what is causing these reboots? Like what systemd service or cron job? I've looked at the cronjobs and none of them had to do with reboots. I have also looked through systemctl, journalctl but could not find any details regarding what process/setting/job started these reboots.

Also, am I correct in assuming that since I see the kernel version number increasing over time, our system is updating the kernel with these reboots?

The context to these questions is that after the system reboot on Nov 12, it overwrote our /etc/resolv.conf and broke our services. We want to prevent this from happening again. The bottom line is we will make our dns settings resilient to changes; but we also want to get to the root cause of these reboots and what looks to be subsequent, kernel updates.

Thanks!

```
$ last | grep boot
reboot   system boot  4.18.0-425.3.1.e Tue Nov 15 14:49   still running
reboot   system boot  4.18.0-425.3.1.e Tue Nov 15 14:37 - 14:49  (00:11)
reboot   system boot  4.18.0-425.3.1.e Sat Nov 12 06:17 - 14:49 (3+08:31)
reboot   system boot  4.18.0-372.26.1. Sat Oct 15 06:06 - 06:16 (28+00:09)
reboot   system boot  4.18.0-372.19.1. Sat Oct  8 12:05 - 06:16 (34+18:10)
reboot   system boot  4.18.0-372.19.1. Sat Oct  1 12:05 - 12:04 (6+23:59)
reboot   system boot  4.18.0-372.19.1. Sat Sep 24 12:04 - 12:04 (7+00:00)
reboot   system boot  4.18.0-372.19.1. Sat Sep 17 12:09 - 12:03 (6+23:54)
reboot   system boot  4.18.0-372.16.1. Sat Sep 10 12:03 - 12:08 (7+00:04)
reboot   system boot  4.18.0-372.16.1. Sat Sep  3 12:04 - 12:03 (6+23:58)
reboot   system boot  4.18.0-372.16.1. Sat Aug 27 12:05 - 12:04 (6+23:59)
reboot   system boot  4.18.0-372.16.1. Sat Aug 20 12:05 - 12:04 (6+23:59)
reboot   system boot  4.18.0-372.16.1. Sat Aug 13 12:05 - 12:04 (13+23:58)
reboot   system boot  4.18.0-372.13.1. Sat Aug  6 12:05 - 12:05 (7+00:00)
reboot   system boot  4.18.0-372.13.1. Sat Jul 30 12:06 - 12:04 (6+23:58)
reboot   system boot  4.18.0-372.13.1. Fri Jul 29 14:44 - 12:04  (21:19)
reboot   system boot  4.18.0-372.13.1. Sat Jul 23 12:06 - 12:04 (6+23:57)
reboot   system boot  4.18.0-372.9.1.e Mon Jul 18 14:04 - 12:04 (11+22:00)
reboot   system boot  4.18.0-372.9.1.e Thu Jul 14 14:01 - 12:04 (15+22:03)
reboot   system boot  4.18.0-372.9.1.e Wed Jun 22 13:01 - 14:00 (22+00:58)
```

Commands I've ran: (if you want to see any of these outputs, let me know!)

```
$ last reboot
$ last -F | grep "Nov 12"
$ sudo journalctl --list-boots
$ sudo journalctl -b -3 -n
$ find /boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-*
$ find /boot/vmli*
$ stat /boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-425.3.1.el8.x86_64
$ sudo journalctl --boot | grep "Linux version"
$ sudo systemctl --type=service
$ sudo crontab -l
```

EDIT: Requested command and output

```
$ last -x shutdown
shutdown system down  4.18.0-425.3.1.e Tue Nov 15 14:49 - 14:49  (00:00)
shutdown system down  4.18.0-372.26.1. Sat Nov 12 06:16 - 06:17  (00:00)
shutdown system down  4.18.0-372.19.1. Sat Oct  8 12:04 - 12:05  (00:00)
shutdown system down  4.18.0-372.19.1. Sat Oct  1 12:04 - 12:05  (00:00)
shutdown system down  4.18.0-372.19.1. Sat Sep 24 12:03 - 12:04  (00:00)
shutdown system down  4.18.0-372.16.1. Sat Sep 17 12:08 - 12:09  (00:00)
shutdown system down  4.18.0-372.16.1. Sat Sep 10 12:03 - 12:03  (00:00)
shutdown system down  4.18.0-372.16.1. Sat Sep  3 12:04 - 12:04  (00:00)
shutdown system down  4.18.0-372.16.1. Sat Aug 27 12:04 - 12:05  (00:00)
shutdown system down  4.18.0-372.13.1. Sat Aug 13 12:05 - 12:05  (00:00)
shutdown system down  4.18.0-372.13.1. Sat Aug  6 12:04 - 12:05  (00:00)
shutdown system down  4.18.0-372.13.1. Sat Jul 30 12:04 - 12:06  (00:01)
shutdown system down  4.18.0-372.9.1.e Thu Jul 14 14:00 - 14:01  (00:00)
shutdown system down  4.18.0-372.9.1.e Wed Jun 22 13:01 - 13:01  (00:00)
```

Comment: What is the content of the result of the `last -x shutdown` command?

Comment: Note that the contents of the ones indicating `system boot` is not really a reboot, but a startup. There may be occasions when the system starts up without a restart command, for example after a power loss.

Comment: If your system has `auditd`, it's a good place to check different events using `ausearch`. To check the `system_boot` and `system_shutdown` inputs use: `sudo ausearch -i -m system_boot,system_shutdown`

Comment: I was not able to install `auditd` with yum. Maybe I'll try compiling it.